# Migration from GLFW + AntTweakBar to SDL2 + ImGui performance issues

Tags: opengl, sdl-2, glfw

I just migrated it an single animation app (just one model) from GLFW+AntTweakBar to SDL2+ImGui .

OpenGL code is the same but i am seem to experiencing more than half of FPS drop
with SDL2+ImGui .

While on GLFW i have an average fps of 100 and on SDL2 i have an average of 30-40. 
SDL/GL init code is below :

```
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_FLAGS, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_FORWARD_COMPATIBLE_FLAG);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_CORE);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 3);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 2);

    SDL_DisplayMode current;
    SDL_GetCurrentDisplayMode(0, &current);

    gWindow = SDL_CreateWindow("", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, windowWidth, windowHeight, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE);
    if (gWindow == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Window could not be created! SDL Error: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        success = false;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << std::endl << "Yay! Created window sucessfully!" << std::endl << std::endl;
        //Create context
        gContext = SDL_GL_CreateContext(gWindow);
        if (gContext == NULL)
        {
            std::cout << "OpenGL context could not be created! SDL Error: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
            success = false;
        }
        else
        {
            //Initialize GLEW
            glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
            GLenum glewError = glewInit();
            if (glewError != GLEW_OK)
            {
                std::cout << "Error initializing GLEW! " << glewGetErrorString(glewError) << std::endl;
            }

            //Use Vsync
            if (SDL_GL_SetSwapInterval(1) < 0)
            {
                std::cout << "Warning: Unable to set Vsync! SDL Error: " << SDL_GetError << std::endl;
            }
```

If i try setting SDL_GL_SetSwapInterval(0) for immediate update i get an average of 60FPS but it still doesn't look smooth and there is small tearing on the model.

I tried removing the ImGui code and it's a better as it ought to be but still much worse performance . 
Is this normal ?

Comment: If vsync is on and frame rate is a bit lower than 60 fps (on 60Hz monitor) - it will drop to 30. If no vsync is up you're very likely to see tearing. Both of that is normal and expected. But if you do the same workload (or even lower) and have different performance - something is amiss, and it unlikely to be in presented code.

Comment: I set SDL_GL_DEPTH_SIZE to 24bits instead of 16 and the tearing stopped . Still though FPS remained the same (~30-40) . If i remove ImGUI it improves a bit but not so much so i am guessing it does not have to do with it. The model rendering function is the same as with glfw. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Maybe it is different GL version. You can try capturing GL commands with apitrace for both programs.

Comment: Havent tried apitrace yet but i will . Although i noticed that running the executable not in debug mode from visual studio gave it a fps average around 58 which is better. Still low to 100 with Glfw.